# getrawchangeaddress: dial tcp [::1]:8080: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: tcp

I am using the decred atomic swap, and no matter what port I set the testnet to use, it says connection refused. I backpropagated the dependencies and everything seems to be working properly, what is poassibly causing the block for the tcp connection?

All help and advice is appreciated :)